# Does Java compiler understand two returns?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, return

Is it safe to write something like this in java?

```
if(var==2){
 return true;
}
return false;
```

Somehow, while debugging, the compiler executes the first return, and goes to the second.
Shouldnt the method be terminated after the first return?

Comment: you probably didn't recompile your code/refresh the workspace so debugger is still using old line numbers.

Comment: Sometimes, the debugger highlights the wrong line. Only one return is executed.

Comment: The *compiler* understands them. I think you meant to ask whether the *debugger* understands them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's safe.

But consider writing this instead:

```
return (var==2);
```

Comment: @Peter: Indeed, most people do.  I tend to leave the parentheses in, because I find it makes things like `boolean c = a == b;` easier to read at a glance.

Comment: Or even `c == a == b` ;) My IDE tells me if parenthesis are redundant, and usually I take that suggestion unless it involves operators I don't often use.

Comment: If you do this, you cannot put a breakpoint on just _one_ of the returns.  This is so useful when debugging I never use the short form.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - In most IDEs you can put a conditional break point on the return for just the case `var == 2` or `var != 2`.

Comment: @TedHopp so where did the advantage go then?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - It's easier to read in a few ways. First, there are fewer lines for your eye to parse. Second, it's immediately clear that you are returning at that point; with an `if`, you have to get to the line after the `if` to see that this is definitely the end of the control flow. Third, it's semantically clearer, I think (as is the verbal form: "`var` is 2" versus "`true` if `var` is 2; `false` otherwise".)

Comment: @TedHopp, taste differs, and I like the if-version better.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - I agree that it's entirely a matter of taste. Unless someone takes a job where coding standards dictate one style, there's no reason for anyone to change from whatever they're used to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's perfectly fine to do that, even though you can write it shorter than that. Perhaps it just looks like it's getting to your second return while you're visually stepping through your code, when `var == 2`, but it's stepping to the end of the function. You should be able to check the return value of the function after it's finished executing.

If you really wanted to be sure, you could use `assert` statements or even a print statement with the return value.

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly safe. Alternatives are `return var == 2;` or `return var == 2 ? true : false;`

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly safe and valid Java code. And it's not possible for the return to not actually return.

If you believe it is, I suggest you do a clean and then  recompile, it's possible there is a mismatch between the compiled class and your source code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe! You can have as many returns as you want - the method will be terminated after the first one